# Combine two result set having no relation

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have two table called table `a` and `b` and that has below data

Table `a` contain data

```
ID Value Score 
1  99.90 100   
2  98.60 200   
3  97.05 300   
4  95.06 400   
5  94.01 500
```

Table `b` contain below data

```
ID Value 
1  96 
2  95
```

And i want result for both table and here the `B.value` is depend on the `a.value`. For example if `b.value` is `96` then I want the value of `97.05` means i want equal or nerest correspond higher value form a

Sample output

```
b.value a.value 
96       97.05
95       95.05
```

Comment: You don't explain *why* `97.05` should be returned from `a` if there's a `96` in your `b` table.

Comment: I want the equal or nerest value of correspond

Comment: Ok, so why return `97.05` for `95`? Also `95.06` is *nearer* to `96` then `97.05` is.

Comment: i want equal or nerest correspond higher value form a

Comment: Please clarify if `Value` in each table can hold duplicate values. You do not say otherwise, but the solution would be a lot simpler if this were the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if im understanding you correctly this will do what you want.

```
SELECT MIN(a.value), b.value 
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b ON a.value > b.value
GROUP BY b.value
```

[DEMO1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68d98/2)

## EDIT:

to include other columns like the score you have to do it like so:

```
SELECT a_val, a.score, b_val 
FROM(
  SELECT MIN(a.value) as a_val, b.value as b_val
  FROM tablea a
  JOIN tableb b ON a.value > b.value
  GROUP BY b.value 
) t
JOIN tablea a ON a.value = t.a_val
```

[DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68d98/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot i have this join but not do group by

Comment: @ManishaPatel you need to group by something in order to not show only one row.. the aggregate MIN() will make it show only one row.. if you group by b.value it will be one b value and the next highest a value for that b value.. look at the demo I posted :)

Comment: @Jhon Ruddell Sir but i have one more question in this a.score is not corraspond to the min(a.value). Can You help me. Now my query is like below "SELECT MIN(a.value), b.value ,a.score 
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b ON a.value > b.value
GROUP BY b.value"

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is very help full to me